# PHP array undefined index notice

Tags: php, arrays

When I print an array  with

```
print_r($item)
```

I get a result

```
Array(
[First Name] => Sam
[Gender] => 2
[Last Name] => Smith
)
```

But when I do `echo $item['First Name']` I receive PHP notice undefined index. Why does it happen?

Comment: Are you sure that variable contains those values when you try to use it? You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to prove this doesn't work because I am sure it does.

Comment: It's easier when you write variable names in the camel case (array indexes here). Ex: `array('firstName' => 'Sam', 'gender' => 2, 'lastName' => 'Smith')`; Then use `$item['fisrtName'];`

Comment: You need to show the line that if producing the PHP notice. It's likely being cause by something else on the same line.

Comment: @JohnConde I was reading the values from csv file and converting it into an array and accessing the value. After some debugging I identified that the issue was caused due to encoding. Once the file was encoded into UTF8 the issue got resolved. If the initial print_r had shown some special characters or symbols may be I would have noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have this structure in the associative array:

```
$item = ['First Name' => 'Sam', 'Gender' => 2, 'Last Name' => 'Smith'];

echo $item['First Name'];
```

`echo $item['First Name'];` will output: `Sam`